# How to reach inside <main> tags using selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using `Python 2.7.12` and `Selenium 3.0.2`.

I wanted to find a tag inside tag `<section>`, here is the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.semanticscholar.org/")
input_t = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="search"]')
input_t.send_keys(keyword)
input_t.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//main')
```

Running this, I got an exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//main"}

But actually, there is indeed a  tag in the page:

```
<main class="main-column results" data-reactid=".dyth4mk2kg.0.1.0.1"><div class="controls" data-reactid=".dyth4mk2kg.0.1.0.1.1">
...
</main>
```

Comment: Are you moving to other pages? because in the page opened from the url there isn't any `<main>` tag.

Comment: Re-edited. Thank you, Guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just timing issue. You should try using [`Explicit Waits`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait until `main` tag loaded and visible after clicking on search button as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.semanticscholar.org/")

#Now enter text to search
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(keyword)

#Now click on search button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".search-bar .button").click()

#Now wait until main tag visible
target = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "main.main-column.results")))
```